# How to take threaddump from docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker, coreos

My application running core OS and Ubuntu in a docker. How to collect thread dump from these systems to analyse the performance issues

i have tried below commands but it didn't work:

```
kill -3
jstack
docker exec
appsnap
```

Answer (score 5):

I have a `java` application running inside a docker and i use: `docker exec -it <containerName> jstack > someFile.txt`

Just make sure to collect it periodically to have a better understanding.

Aslo, You can use applications like `yourkit` to do it for you

Answer (score 0):

There are several threaddump shell scripts which may help you on https://access.redhat.com/solutions/18178 (at the bottom under attatchments).

Basic usage:

```
sh ./threaddump_linux.sh JAVA_PID
```

You'll have to add this to your Dockerfile or exec in to your container and manually install and run it.

The instructions for using them (plus other techniques for thread dumping) are on that page

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the container was built, `jstack` may not be available:

```
$ docker exec -it mycontainer jstack
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "jstack": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

You'd have to install the JDK package in the container first, which seems a bit drastic.

One thing that worked for me was to use the QUIT signal method to obtain a stack dump. This should work for all containers, not just Ubuntu.

To generate the dump, attach to the container and find the PID of the java process. The PID in the container is not the same as outside of the container.

**UPDATE**: You can send the `QUIT` signal to the process from *outside* the container (on the host), if you can find the right PID.

You may find that the `pidof` and in some cases even `ps` utilities are not installed in the container. If all fails, you can find the PID in the `/proc` filesystem:

```
$ docker exec -it mycontainer /bin/sh
sh-4.2$ find /proc -maxdepth 2 -name "cmdline" -exec grep '[j]ava' '{}' \;
Binary file /proc/1709/cmdline matches
```

The PID we need is 1709. If `find` is also not available, you can manually search through the process directories in `/proc` using `cat /proc/<PID>/cmdline`.

Now send the QUIT signal to that PID (again, this is in the container):

```
sh-4.2$ kill -QUIT 1709
```

Now you have to figure out where the `stdout` of the process goes to. In my case I got lucky, and `stdout` ended up in the docker logs (on the host):

```
$ docker logs --since 1m mycontainer
2022-10-19 09:33:01
Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.5+10-LTS mixed mode, sharing):

Threads class SMR info:
[ .... ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the cases I know, the java process inside the container has pid 1. So I can trigger the thead dump with

```
docker exec -it <containerName> kill -3 1
```

and then harvest the output with

```
docker logs <containerName>
```